# How to optimize Animated CustomView inside ListView item

Tags: android, animation, optimization, android-listview, android-custom-view

I have this layout for `ListView` item

```
<com.example.donutgraph.TalkingFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp" >

        <com.example.donutgraph.GaugeView
            android:id="@+id/gauge"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</com.example.donutgraph.TalkingFrameLayout>
```

The one which animated is a `GaugeView`. I create a simple time-based animation which will invalidate the view like this

```
    private Runnable animator = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ....
                update(now);
                if (!isFinish()) {
                    needNewFrame = true;
                } else {
                    Log.e(tag, "millisecond : " + (now - startTime));
                }

                if (needNewFrame) {
                    postDelayed(this, timeBetweenFrame);
                }
                invalidate();
            }
        };
private void update(long now) {

        float dt = Math.min(now - lastTime, timeBetweenFrame);

        currentTime += dt;
        if (currentTime > duration) {
            currentTime = duration;
        }
    }
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
       ....
       float percent = getPercentForTime(currentTime);
       canvas.drawArc(rectF, 270, percent * -360.0f, false, paint);
       ....
       canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(percentInt), xPos, yPos, paint);

}
```

This is the result I archieve

[image]

The problem here is because of animation need to call invalidate so it invoke all onDraw() in a hierarchy which I don't want and I think because of that it made my `ListView` so laggy when scrolling during the animation. When no animation on this GaugeView ListView runs smoothly.

Anyway to optimize this so that I can scroll smoothly?

and also is there anyway to prevent invalidate() call to invoke onDraw() on all view hierarchy? because everything is the same except the `GaugeView` which will animate and it is the only one that changing. It seem like a waste to call `onDraw()` on my `TalkingFrameLayout` again and again without changing.

Thanks